# Choose which version of python to use when installing with yum

Tags: python, linux, centos, yum

I have 3 versions of Python on my Linux VPS (CentOS). Version 2.6 is the system python. I want to install modules to python 2.7 but running the following command just installs to python 2.6. How do I specify python 2.7 in this command?

```
yum install python-devel
```

Thanks!

Comment: How did you install the other versions of Python?

Comment: # wget http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.3/Python-2.7.3.tar.bz2
# tar xf Python-2.7.3.tar.bz2
# cd Python-2.7.3
# ./configure --prefix=/usr/local
# make && make altinstall

Comment: If you built Python from source, how do you expect `yum` to be able to install their development files? Luckily you should already have the development files from installing from source.

Comment: @macdonjo how did you solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the default version of python using the "alternatives" system. Try

```
>> /usr/sbin/alternatives --configure python
```

If this has no effect, try to find the python version in use and modify the symlinks accordingly

```
>> which python
```

If the result, for example, is /usr/local/bin/python and the version of python you want to use is at /usr/bin/python2.7 then do

```
>> ln -sf /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/python
```

Comment: Does this work on CentOS? I thought the alternatives system was a Debian thing.

Comment: Centos does support alternatives. See for e.g. http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/JavaRuntimeEnvironment

Comment: `/usr/sbin/alternatives --config`  (instead of `configure` ) in centos 7.2 at least...

Comment: Slight hijack, but note that if you've stumbled upon this question from a requires: python(abi) = X.Y problem on CentOS, this solution will not fix it. I've used pyenv combined with the solution above and it does not solve that requirement problem. rpm -q --provides python | grep abi will tell you what abis are installed. I will update this comment once I find a solution.